# Create XML based on condition Linq to XML

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

Fairly new with Linq to XML and scratching my head over this one. I am creating an XML document using Xdocument by getting some data from a database and then usng a for each statement and adding each data line i.e.

```
    Dim MyCustomers As IQueryable(Of Customer) = GetCUstomers
    Dim XDoc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?<Customers></Customers>

    For Each c As Customer In MyCustomers
    Xdoc.Root.Add(<CustomerID=<%= c.Id %> 
     <FirstName><%= c.Name %></FirstName>
     <Surname><%= c.Surname %></Surname>
    Next
```

I would like to have an If statment so if Surname is empty i want that element to be removed completely.

So if a customer's surname exists the XML is

```
<CustomerID=123> 
<FirstName>Name</FirstName>
<Surname>Surname></Surname>
```

If not

```
<CustomerID=123> 
<FirstName>Name</FirstName>
```

I have tried using

```
<%= If (string.IsnullEmpty(c.Surname) Then %>
```

and other combinations, but whatever i try i get a syntax error. Ive searched MSDN and most examples refer to getting nodes but not creating nodes/elements in an XML file based on a condition. Im really lost in how to approach this one?

Could anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe some of the code got garbled - there are some invalid XML elements, such as `<CustomerID=123>`, which perhaps should be `<Customer ID=123>`.  That said, the following (runnable in LINQPad) does what you want, I think, and hopefully you can adapt it to your code.

```
Sub Main
    Dim MyCustomers = New List(Of Customer)() From {
        New Customer() With { .ID = 1, .Name = "Cust1", .Surname = "Surn1" },
        New Customer() With { .ID = 2, .Name = "Cust2" },
        New Customer() With { .ID = 3, .Name = "Cust3", .Surname = "Surn3" },
        New Customer() With { .ID = 4, .Name = "Cust4" }
    }
    Dim Xdoc = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Customers></Customers>
    For Each c As Customer In MyCustomers
        Dim cust = 
            <Customer ID=<%= c.Id %>>
                <FirstName><%= c.Name %></FirstName>
            </Customer>
        If c.Surname IsNot Nothing Then
            cust.Add(<Surname><%= c.Surname %></Surname>)
        End If
        Xdoc.Root.Add(cust)
    Next
    Xdoc.Dump()
End Sub

' Define other methods and classes here
Public Class Customer
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Surname As String
End Class
```

**Update**

Here is the above loop, but using an embedded LINQ query to selectively add the `<Surname>` element. Personally I find the logic above more readable, but both produce the same output.

```
For Each c As Customer In MyCustomers
    Xdoc.Root.Add(
        <Customer ID=<%= c.Id %>>
            <FirstName><%= c.Name %></FirstName>
            <%= From sn In New String() { c.Surname }
                Where sn IsNot Nothing
                Select <Surname><%= sn %></Surname>
            %>
        </Customer>
    )
Next
```

Here is the output:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer ID="1">
    <FirstName>Cust1</FirstName>
    <Surname>Surn1</Surname>
  </Customer>
  <Customer ID="2">
    <FirstName>Cust2</FirstName>
  </Customer>
  <Customer ID="3">
    <FirstName>Cust3</FirstName>
    <Surname>Surn3</Surname>
  </Customer>
  <Customer ID="4">
    <FirstName>Cust4</FirstName>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Comment: Thanks - this unfortunately doesnt help my case as im struggling with the code within the XDoc.Root.Add as its here i need to state if that line of XML is required or not. AFAIK the syntax begins with <%=

Comment: @Computer I think what you are running into is that it is not valid to put conditional logic into [XML literal expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384964.aspx). You can include queries - I'll update the answer with an example that would **also** do what you want.